# MARIADB - Python Connection Issue

Tags: python, mariadb

Issue - On CENTOS 7, I have installed MARIADB 10.x which is working perfectly fine, I tested with DBeaver.

to connect MARIA DB 10.x from PYTHON 2.7, I have installed "MySQL-python 1.2.5" as recommended "https://mariadb.com/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb".

But getting below error while testing, Please help with this.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

The lib [MySQLdb1](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1) is not maintained anymore. The MySQL company maintain a connector project.

Use [MySQL Connector for Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) as MariaDB database connection.

```
import MySQLdb as mariadb
conn = mariadb.connect(user='username', passwd='1a2b3c', db='defaultdb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

The lib mentioned on MariaDB [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) is the one officialy builded by MySQL. Using this lib you will be able to follow the tutorial.

As [@nizam-mohamed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4522780/nizam-mohamed) mentioned in comments, there is a a fork from MySQLdb1, [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/).

Comment: this worked fine, but seems this is old libraries. And, any reason why mysql.connector is not working

Comment: The connector described on MariaDB  docs is the one offered by [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)